# How to stick the footer to bottom and stretch sidebar and content divs to the footer?

Tags: css, html

How do I stick the footer to the bottom of the screen and stretch sidebar and content divs to the footer? Is it possible without using JavaScript? I have found ways to stick the footer to bottom, but I don't know how to make the sidebar equal i size to the content if it has less text.

If the height of the content is more than the viewport height, scroll bars should appear.

[image: What I need]

Comment: have you tried using a table and setting row width, then data cell width and height?

Comment: <table>
<tr>
<td class="header"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="sidebar"></td>
<td class="content"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="footer"></td>
</tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the flex model, i would go this way:

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;/* includes borders & padding  into size calculation*/
  white-space: pre;/* demo purpose only */
}
html:hover {font-size:2em;/* demo purpose only */}
html {
  height: 100%;/* needed so can be inherited & used by body */
}
body {
  height: 100%;/* it can grow */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column;
      -ms-flex-flow: column;
          flex-flow: column;
  margin: 0;/* reset */
}
main {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;/* fill up whole space avalaible */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;/* inbrication for side by side same height children */
}
header,
footer {
  background: #7092BF;
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  /* no height or flex value needed */
}
section {
  border: solid;
  background: #9AD9EA;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1/* fill up whole space avalaible */
}
aside {
  border: solid;
  width: 200px;/* any value/unit */
  background: #3E48CC
}
```

```html
<header>  any height header</header>
<main>
  <aside>    aside
    aside
    aside
    aside  </aside>
  <section>        Hover me & test me full page too
    content
    content
    content
    content  </section>
</main>
<footer>  any height footer
  any height footer</footer>
```

Comment: This code does not work in IE11, are there any solutions?

Comment: @J.Doe for ie , turn min-height:100%; to height:100%; for body, that should do, else tell me what is it that is not working :)

Comment: With min-height it looks like that http://i.stack.imgur.com/qkBl7.png and with height like that http://i.imgur.com/r41yKuq.png

Comment: @J.Doe i added prefixe and updated CSS snippet , you may download a zip file here too : http://codepen.io/anon/share/zip/wWzPGQ/

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this; the CSS 'vh' and 'vw' units may be the simplest, especially if you have a fixed-height header and/or footer:

```css
body{margin:0}
div {border: 1px solid;box-sizing: border-box; background-color:#EEE}

.container {width: 100vw; height: 100vh}

.header, .footer {width: 100vw; height: 60px}

.sidebar, .body {
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebar {width: 20%; float:left}
.body {width: 80%; float:right}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
  <div class="body">BODY</div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, flexbox:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-model: border-box
}
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #EEE
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
.innercontainer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.body {
  flex-grow: 1
}
.sidebar,
.body {
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="innercontainer">
    <div class="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
    <div class="body">BODY</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, excuse me, I wasn't quite clear. I meant to say that the whole page should scroll, not individual divs.

Comment: Ah, that'd just be a matter of putting the `overflow:scroll` on the `.innercontainer` (or, possibly, omitting it altogether)

Answer (score 0):

This will work on any screen size all the time. Just change the values to suit your needs.

```
<body>
<header style="height: 10vh;position: relative;">HEADER</header>
    <nav style="bottom: 0;position: fixed;top: 10vh;width: 20vw;">SIDEBAR</nav>
    <section style="margin-left: 20vw;width: 80vw;">BODY
    </section>
    <footer style="bottom: 0;position: fixed;width: 100vw;">FOOTER</footer>
</body>
```

I left the header to scroll up, but it can be make to remain static on the top.

Additionally, I would move the styles to a stylesheet, but this is faster for this example.

Answer (score -2):

Give your div's a table-like display, or use a table element format.

```
<div width="100%"></div>
<div display="table-cell" width="20%"></div>
<div display="table-cell" width="80%"></div>
<div width="100%"></div>
```

or

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="header"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sidebar"></td>
        <td class="content"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="footer"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)